# How to whitelist url with Cloud DLP?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

I use Cloud DLP for identify sensitive data but I want allow (whitelist) some data so DLP not identify them.

For example by default I want to match URL infoType so DLP identify it. But I also want to allow certain URL from google.com and yahoo.com. How I can do this?

I am use Node.js client library: https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/libraries#using_the_client_library

Answer (score 2):

You can make whitelist through modifying infotype dectectors.

I'm new to GCP DLP, but I was able to find information on GCP document.

Refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/creating-custom-infotypes-rules) to get detailed information.

According to this link, You can specify exclusion rules which can whitelist a dictionary, regex, infotypes.